# Do we have an AWS CLI command that can list free tier AMI's in the region of interest?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Do we have an AWS CLI command that can list free tier AMI's in the region of interest?

Tried the following command.

aws ec2 describe-images --owners self amazon

It is giving all the AMIs in the region.

Comment: All AMIs are effectively free, except for those that contain licensed software (eg SQL Server) where additional charges will apply. Why are you asking? Are you looking for a particular Operating System or wanting some pre-installed software?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter on the FreeTierEligible value, try something like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types --filters "Name=free-tier-eligible,Values=true"
```